# Sorting an array of objects by their assigned integer values

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects containing the following data.

```
unsortedArray = 
A : 1
B : 2
C : 3
D : 4
E : 5
F : 6
G : 7
H : 8
I : 9
J : 10
K : 11
L : 12
M : 13
N : 14
O : 15
P : 16
Q : 17
R : 18
S : 19
T : 20
U : 21
V : 22
W : 23
X : 24
Y : 25
Z : 26
```

I'm trying to sort these objects so that the objects with the higher integer values appear further up in the list, but am receiving the following output with the sort..

```
sortedArray = 
Z : 26
X : 24
W : 23
V : 22
U : 21
T : 20
S : 19
R : 18
Q : 17
P : 16
O : 15
N : 14
M : 13
L : 12
K : 11
J : 10
I : 9
H : 8
G : 7
F : 6
E : 5
D : 4
C : 3
B : 2
Y : 25
A : 1
```

Below is the code I am using..

```
var sortedArray= unsortedArray;
Array.Sort(sortedArray, (x, y) => y.Point >= x.Point ? y.Point : x.Point);
```

Note: In the code, `Point` refers to the integer value in the object.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Your delegate should return 0, 1 or -1. Try `(x,y) => xPoint.CompareTo(y.Point)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument you pass to `Array.Sort` is an `IComparer<T>`. From the documentation:

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 A signed integer that indicates the
>   relative values of x and y, as shown in the following table.
>
> [image]

If you return a value according to the above table and use `Sort`, the array will be sorted in ascending order, which is the opposite of what you want. This means that you should return a negative value if x is larger than y, and a positive value if x is less than y!

```
Array.Sort(sortedArray, (x, y) => y.Point - x.Point);
```

Comment: I would caution against using `y.Point - x.Point` for the return value. Integer overflow rears its ugly head in curious places and causes some difficult to find bugs. I would recommend `y.CompareTo(x)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
Array.Sort(sortedArray, (x, y) => y.Point >= x.Point ? y.Point : x.Point);
```

with

```
Array.Sort(sortedArray, (x, y) => y.Point >= x.Point ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: Some sorting algorithms will go into an infinite loop if you treat equal items as greater (or less). Strangely enough, they expect that if comparing x to y returns 1, then comparing y to x will return -1. Bad things happen if that isn't true.